# Definition of $dz_i\otimes d\bar{z_j}(\frac{\partial}{\partial z_m},c\frac{\partial}{\partial z_n})$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, complex-geometry

Is $dz_i\otimes d\bar{z_j}(\frac{\partial}{\partial z_m},c\frac{\partial}{\partial z_n}):=dz_i(\frac{\partial}{ \partial z_m})d\bar{z_j}(\bar{c}\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z_n}})$?

[image]

It seems that by the word above, it follows that $dz_i\otimes d\bar{z_j}(\frac{\partial}{\partial z_i},c\frac{\partial}{\partial z_j}):=dz_i(\frac{\partial}{ \partial z_i})d\bar{z_j}(\bar{c}\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z_j}})=\bar{c}$.

But I don't know if it's a convention to take the conjugate of the coordinate corresponding to the $\bar{z_j}$ or is there a reason? Because in my view (maybe not right),
$dz_i\otimes d\bar{z_j}(\frac{\partial}{\partial z_i},c\frac{\partial}{\partial z_j})$ should be $dz_i(\frac{\partial}{\partial z_i})d\bar{z_j}(c\frac{\partial}{\partial z_j})=1\cdot 0=0$.

Reference: Griffith and Harris p.27

Comment: Please put the exact reference... In any case, I think I recognize your unhappiness: this is Griffith and Harris, right?

Comment: @peterag yes, it's Griffith and Harris p.27

Comment: please see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13000/errata-to-principles-of-algebraic-geometry-by-griffiths-and-harris

Comment: @peterag thanks, and so it's not sesquilinear?

Comment: There is much more to say! I wonder whether someone ever did write up the errata. As you might gather, I have been in your situation... There are 'typos' in the foundational stuff in GH, and I think that one should not take signs too seriously, and I think they vary conventions as they go along. I also never followed their version of the proof of Hodge (harmonic reps for the coho classes), although it may well be correct - I ended up beating a retreat to Warner's book, which I did understand. To answer your sesqui-lin question: Certainly, one needs $(v,v)\ge 0$ if the form is pos def. (cont)

Comment: I'll try to write up something more serious by Monday if no one else (more competent!)  does. It's quite an exercise to do a GH exegesis justice. BTW, if I am sounding negative, well, I think it's a great book, but...

Comment: @peterag Thank you for these words and I am looking forward to your more serious comments

Comment: @peterag I feel confused with the errata now, if you add the bar on the second entry then it's not defined on the holomorphic tangent bundle as he defined. Isn't it a contradiction?

Comment: As I wrote, give me a bit of time to write this up, as I understand it! But yes, I agree, GH is confusing. On page 71 the notation for a hermitian i p  $(,\cdot,\cdot)$ is the usual: a map on $V\times V \to {\mathbb C}$, linear in the first component, anti on the second ($V$ a cx vs), as one usually understand it, as in the notation  in my previous component, and as in the i p notation defining $h_{ij}$ above. On the other hand, it does not match the declaration of the i p as a map on $V\otimes \overline V$. (cont)

Comment: (cont) Actually I had another continuation comment here (referring to the real structure of $V$), but I have deleted it, as it was incomplete - again, allow me time to be more comprehensive....

Comment: I am obviously not delivering by Monday, as promised - but are you OK? is Ted S's answer below sufficient?

Comment: @peterag I am ok, Ted's answer is nice. And if you can give your answer, then that will be great and I will be happy to check and learn from you. But if you feel too stressful to give an answer and want to give up then I can also understand. Moreover, if you want to give an answer but need more time, please take your time.

Answer (score 5):

There are indeed various typos and issues in Griffiths and Harris. Signs in complex geometry are always a bugaboo, too; even Chern had the sign wrong in defining $c_1$ in the first edition of his *Complex Manifolds without Potential Theory*.

G/H are inconsistent here. A hermitian metric should be given on the complex vector space $T'_z(M)$, so, as such we feed in two (holomorphic) tangent vectors. Let's think about $\Bbb C$: To get sesquilinearity, we need to take $dz\otimes d\bar z$, with the understanding that $d\bar z(v) = \overline{dz(v)}$. Then $\|v\|^2 = dz\otimes d\bar z(v,v)$. On the other hand, if you think of the hermitian metric as giving a bilinear map on $T'_z(M)\times T''_z(M)$, then we take $\|v\|^2 = dz\otimes d\bar z(v,\bar v)$. Because we're going to work primarily with differential forms we really prefer to work with the latter interpretation, thinking of the hermitian metric as a $(2,0)$ tensor on the complexified tangent space.

By the way, there's a sign error on the top of p. 29. There should be a negative sign in the first displayed equation giving the definition of a positive $(1,1)$-form.

Comment: I was going to mention that negative sign on p 29!

Comment: So $d\bar z(v) = \overline{dz(v)}$ is a definition?

Comment: @Danny: If you want to think of the hermitian metric as a function on the complex (holomorphic) tangent space, but that's not how they defined it. They're using the second definition, working on the complexified tangent space, so you then have $\|v\|^2 = h(v,\bar v)$, not $h(v,v)$. As I said, this works out better when we get to differential forms (think about integrating $dz\wedge d\bar z = -2i dx\wedge dy$ — you want to feed in not just holomorphic tangent vectors!).

Comment: ... So, given the way they're defining the hermitian metric, they should have written $h_{ij}(z) = \big(\partial/\partial z_i,\partial/\partial\bar z_j\big)_z$. But that's not how most of us think of a hermitian metric on a fixed complex vector space. They're complexifying the vector space to start with.

Comment: A Hermitian inner product is sesquilinear, but if we consider the hermitian metric on $T’M\times T”M$, I don’t think it’s sesquilinear, so is that a contradiction?

Comment: Danny, there are two different—but —notions going on here, as I tried to make clear with my $\Bbb C$ example.  Thinking of it as a bilinear form on $T'\times T''$ is equivalent to thinking of it as sesquilinear on $T'$.